# Active or enable app in device administrator without user interaction

Tags: java, android, shell, command, adb

i am developing an applocker application in android.so to prevent user from clearing data,i need to disable clear button in settings which i can achieve by adding my app in device administrator..i am able to achieve that using this code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dpm set-device-owner com.example.hp.useradministratordemo/.DemoFrag");
```

but my app is not active or enabled in device administrator and this process i want to do without user interaction..I searched for that and i found that there is one command "set-active-admin" but i don't know how to use this shell command
..thanks in advance

Comment: If it is possible to make an app be a device administrator without user interaction, that would be a major security flaw in Android.

Comment: i can understand but i have to do that in order to provide security to user..

Comment: How do you plan to deliver app that has to be `device owner`?

Comment: i have found syntax of set-active-admin but i can't understand how to use it

Comment: dpm set-active-admin [ --user <USER_ID> | current ] <COMPONENT>

Comment: "i have to do that in order to provide security to user" -- no, you do not. The user is perfectly capable of using the Settings app to make your app be a device administrator.

Comment: i am using this reference

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock

Comment: this app doesn't ask to user to enable or activate user administrator but silently it enables..

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani did you found any solution ? I am stuck with this also.  
Please share code if you done with this